# ¿Cómo leer una parte especifica de un archivo binario C, y almacenarlo en otro archivo?

Tags: c

Quiero leer cierta cantidad **K** de bytes en un *archivo binario* a partir de una posición **P** y guardarlo en otro archivo.

Creo que debo hacer uso de la herramienta *fseek*  pero no estoy seguro, cualquier luz me ayudaría. Gracias

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fichero_in;
    fichero_in = fopen("test.bin","rb");    

    FILE *fichero_out;
    fichero_out = fopen("copia.bin","wb");  

    int k = 10;
    int p = 50;
    char *buf;
    buf = malloc(k);

    //¿como hago para leer a partir de la posicion 50?
    // aqui lee desde el inicio.
    fread(buf, 1, k, fichero_in );
    fwrite(buf,1, k, fichero_out);

    fclose(fichero_in);
    fclose(fichero_out);

    free(buf);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## fseek

Definida en la cabecera

int fseek( FILE *stream, long offset, int origen );

coloca la posicion del stream del archivo indicado por *stream* en el valor apuntado por *offset*

## Parametros

stream  -   Archivo stream a modificar
offset  -   numero de caracteres a rodarse desde la posicion relativa a *origen*
origen  -   posicion a la cual el *offset* agregara valores; puede tener uno de los siguientes valores

_SEEK_SET:_ Desde el inicio del archivo
_SEEK_CUR:_ Desde la posición actual
_SEEK_END:_ Desde el final del archivo

*en mi caso la solucion fue:*

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fichero_in;
    fichero_in = fopen("test.bin","rb");    

    FILE *fichero_out;
    fichero_out = fopen("copia.bin","wb");  

    int k = 10;
    long p = 50;


    char *buf;

    buf = malloc(k);

    if (fseek(fichero_in, p,SEEK_SET) != 0)
    {
       if (ferror(fichero_in))
       {
          perror("fseek()");
          fprintf(stderr,"fseek() failed in file %s at line # %d\n", __FILE__,__LINE__-5);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
    }


    fread (buf, 1, k, fichero_in );
    fwrite(buf, 1, k, fichero_out);

    fclose(fichero_in);
    fclose(fichero_out);

    free(buf);

}
```

Con informacion traducida desde [fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)